# How to make smooth LED brightness control without PWM?

Tags: led, led-driver

I want to make a very smooth  adjustment of the brightness of a single 350 mA 2.85 V LED without PWM. And I need to get low brightness values. I do not know how to control the LED properly. Constant current and a adjustable voltage such as "DC dimming" may be suitable. I also found an option on one transistor and want to connect a DAC to it. How to properly control the brightness of the LED without PWM so that it works longer?
[image]

3.1+ kHz pwm for flicker free
[image]
[image]

Comment: But you can use PWM. You can filter it to DC and use it like a DAC. Why not use PWM for DC DAC?

Comment: What is your thinking that suggests to you that you don't want to use PWM?

Comment: Smooth (to me anyway) refers to stepless adjustment or steps that are smaller than human vision  can perceive. Is that what  you mean?

Comment: @Andre by ``control the brightness of the LED without PWM so that it works longer`` do you mean (a) maximise battery life (b) maximise lifetime of the LED (c) or something else?

Comment: One thing though: white LEDs tend to get weird colours (like a greenish hue) at very low currents. This is one reason to use PWM rather than current-based dimming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering the TI [LED drivers](https://www.ti.com/power-management/led-drivers/products.html#480=1&1129=current%20mode&sort=1129;desc&) parametric selection for single channel and *current mode* devices to look for possible devices which don't use PWM.

On possible candidate is the [LM36011 Inductorless LED flash driver](https://www.ti.com/product/LM36011). The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm36011.pdf) shows that it contains a *Torch Mode* described as:

> In torch mode, the LED current source provides 128 target current levels from 2.4 mA to 376 mA, set by the LED
> Torch Brightness Register (0x04 bits [6:0]). Torch mode is activated by the Enable Register (0x01), setting mode M1, M0 (bits [1:0]) to 10. Once the TORCH sequence is activated, the LED current source ramps up to the programmed torch current by stepping through all current steps until the programmed current is reached.

Section *8.2.2.1 Thermal Performance* of the datasheet suggests this is a linear regulator, and therefore doesn't use PWM:

> The device power dissipation equals:
>
> P<sub>DISS</sub> = ( V<sub>IN</sub> - V<sub>LED</sub> ) * I<sub>LED</sub>

While the LM36011 LED current is set by I2C, rather than an analog voltage from a DAC, it might be suitable for a LED with the current controlled by a microcontroller. Even if not directly suitable, indicates what sort of LED driver to look for.

Comment: Since his goal is to maximize battery life, a high efficiency switching driver might make more sense than a linear one. The OP can probably find something similar but switching using the parametric search

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks, I missed the goal to "maximize battery life" and so have now added a comment on the question to seek clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of low duty cycle PWM which can look bad, especially at low frequencies. Current-control LED drivers that switch into an inductor and have a sense element in the loop will not have the flicker of on-off PWM and will give you better control at lower brightness.